# No possible to upgrade expo sdk version

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have a react native expo peoject, I was testing it using expo go on android phone.

But right now I update the movile app and when I try to scan the QR code to test the app, it show me that the sdk expo on the movile just support 47, 45 and 45 sdk version, but the project is using 44 sdk version.

On the project I'm using "expo-cli upgrade" to the the 46 sdk version, but I get this error:

```
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                         │
│   There is a new version of expo-cli available (6.0.8).                 │
│   You are currently using expo-cli 5.1.3                                │
│   Install expo-cli globally using the package manager of your choice;   │
│   for example: `npm install -g expo-cli` to get the latest version      │
│                                                                         │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Warning! Your git working tree is dirty.
It's recommended to commit all your changes before proceeding, so you can revert the changes made by this command if necessary.

√ Would you like to proceed? ... yes

√ You are currently using SDK 44.0.0. Would you like to update to the latest version, 47.0.0? ... yes


× Failed to install expo package with error: yarnpkg exited with non-zero code: 1
yarnpkg exited with non-zero code: 1
Error: yarnpkg exited with non-zero code: 1
    at ChildProcess.completionListener (C:\Users\Bosatzu\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.15.1\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\src\spawnAsync.ts:65:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\Bosatzu\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.15.1\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
    ...
    at Object.spawnAsync [as default] (C:\Users\Bosatzu\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.15.1\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\src\spawnAsync.ts:26:19)
    at YarnPackageManager._runAsync (C:\Users\Bosatzu\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.15.1\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\package-manager\src\NodePackageManagers.ts:309:31)
    at YarnPackageManager.addAsync (C:\Users\Bosatzu\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.15.1\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\package-manager\src\NodePackageManagers.ts:258:16)
    at upgradeAsync (C:\Users\Bosatzu\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.15.1\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\info\upgradeAsync.ts:496:7)
    at actionAsync (C:\Users\Bosatzu\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.15.1\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\info\upgradeAsync.ts:42:3)
```

I'm using SO windows 10.

This is the package.json file:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.35",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome": "^0.2.6",
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^3.6.6",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.15.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "4.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.2.1",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^5.3.15",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.0.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.5",
    "axios": "^0.21.4",
    "core-js": "^3.20.3",
    "expo": "^44.0.0",
    "expo-checkbox": "~2.0.0",
    "expo-cli": "^5.1.3",
    "expo-dev-client": "^0.8.6",
    "expo-font": "~10.0.4",
    "expo-location": "~14.0.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.14.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "expo-updates": "^0.11.7",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "native-base": "^3.1.0",
    "qrcode": "^1.5.0",
    "radio-buttons-react-native": "^1.0.4",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-air-progress-bar": "0.0.5",
    "react-native-backdrop": "^2.1.2",
    "react-native-count-to": "0.0.2",
    "react-native-countdown-component": "^2.7.1",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^4.1.1",
    "react-native-dialog": "^8.0.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-hide-show-password-input": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-ico": "^28.7.4",
    "react-native-ico-material-design": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-maps": "0.29.4",
    "react-native-material-design": "^0.3.7",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^13.0.0",
    "react-native-pager-view": "5.4.9",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.9.2",
    "react-native-propel-kit": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.1.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.3.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.10.1",
    "react-native-snackbar": "^2.4.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-stars": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.15.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4",
    "reanimated-bottom-sheet": "^1.0.0-alpha.22",
    "rn-qr-generator": "^1.2.0",
    "sentry-expo": "^4.0.5",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.1",
    "styled-system": "^5.1.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true,
  "name": "parking-app-front",
  "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

I hope you can help me out with this

Comment: can you share package.json with us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this problem by doing the following steps:

- delete `yarn.lock` or `package-lock.json` and `node_modules`.
- run `yarn install` or run `yarn` (if you are using npm you can run `npm install`.
- if all the above steps worked fine then run `expo upgrade.

this would do the trick.

Comment: I just tried that, but I just got the same error

Comment: did you tried to run this command `npm install -g expo-cli`?

Comment: Yes I did, but the same problem

Comment: could you try this `npx expo upgrade`